# How to standardize datetime format for all regions?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, datetime

Within my program i insert into the sql server the current time into a sql DateTime column.
Because the program is used by users around the world , i found out that some american users are receiving an error (which doesn't cause the program to crash) and i believe this is happening because of different date and time formats.

I use the following line of code to get the current time in a specific time zone but i understand that for different users i will get different time formats.
For example for american users i will get "MM-dd-yyyy" while for european users i will get "dd/MM/yyyy".

```
Dim CurrentTime As DateTime = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("SOME LOCAL TIME ID"))
```

I've been trying to figure out how to standardize this format before inserting to the server without any luck.
Hopefully someone here may be able to help.

Thanks!

Comment: Its more likely related to how you display the Date to those users.  A Date is simply a Long value and it means the same thing to Yanks as Brits as Germans.  How it is displayed is different based on the local culture.  If you convert to string in the program, thats most likely the problem.

Comment: Isn't this a sql server setting? It depends on the locale of the sql server. I am not entirely sure. Not sure if differences between the locale of sql server, and the machine running the .net app will also cause a problem. However, I've given you some avenues to explore. :)

Comment: `for different users i will get different time formats` actually different users will **see** different formats for the same DateTime - *you* dont have to do anything other than store a date.  `theDate.ToString` will display the date according to each user's local settings.  And VS will display the date to you in *your* local format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're storing your DateTime values as UTC values (`GetUTCDate()` vs. `GetDate()`).
Ideally you'd be using `datetime2` rather than `datetime` for your SQL field type, if you're using at least SQL Server 2008.

If you have a DateTime variable in the local time zone, you can convert it to UTC before storing it in SQL Server using [`DateTime.ToUniversalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
dim localDateTime as DateTime
dim storedDateTime as DateTime
localDateTime = DateTime.Now
storedDateTime = localDateTime.ToUniversalTime()
```

Also note the caveat about XP on that linked MSDN page.

When you retrieve the UTC value you can do the timezone adjustment to the local machine's timezone using [`DateTime.ToLocalTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim storedDateTime as DateTime
Dim localDateTime as string
storedDateTime = (DateTime)reader[Timestamp"]
localDateTime = myDateTime.ToLocalTime()
```

To get the correct format for the DateTime string, you should be able to use `DateTime.ToString()`.  This will use the current culture for the thread:

```
Console.WriteLine(localDateTime.ToString())
```

You can override this manually if you like by [specifying the culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim germanCultureInfo As New CultureInfo("de-DE")
Console.WriteLine(localDateTime.ToString(germanCultureInfo))
```

Answer (score 0):

The displaying of dates is a UI problem. Converting from date to text and text to date should be done on the UI with the user current culture or forced through [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx).

All of the business logic and database should not depend on the user culture or timezone. In your case, it would be ideal to have everything stored as UTC.

If you start storing the hour, you'll quickly see how messy it'll get with each country having different DLS.